# Attempt to read Asset file gives file not found exception indicating the file is looked for in C:\WINDOWS\system32

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, maui

Using VS 2022 with a .NET 7 MAUI project I have added a file named `default.xml` to the `Resources\Raw` folder, checked that its build action is MauiAsset and now my code tries to read it with e.g. `InputData = await LoadAsset("default.xml");` where the method `LoadAsset` does e.g.

```
private static async Task<string> LoadAsset(string path)
{
    using var stream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(path);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8);

    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

(I have also tried with `using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(path);`) but for some reasons I don't understand that ends up with an error `$exception    {"Could not find file 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\default.xml'.":"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\default.xml"}  System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

Why does Maui look for the file in C:\Windows\system32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first line you're treating `path` as a package file appropriately - but then you're ignoring `stream` and trying to open it as if it's just a regular file path by passing to the `StreamReader` constructor. Instead, use the stream you've opened:

```cs
private static async Task<string> LoadAsset(string path)
{
    using var stream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(path);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

    return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

(Note that I've changed this to read from the `StreamReader` asynchronously too.)

Comment: Thanks, that looks as if I shot myself into the foot.